# Splitting up group by with relevant aggregates beyond the basic ones?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm not sure if this has been asked before because I'm having trouble even asking it myself. I think the best way to explain my dilemma is to use an example.

Say I've rated my happiness on a scale of 1-10 every day for 10 years and I have the results in a big table where I have a single date correspond to a single integer value of my happiness rating. I say, though, that I only care about my happiness over 60 day periods on average (this may seem weird but this is a simplified example). So I wrap up this information to a table where I now have a start date field, an end date field, and an average rating field where the start days are every day from the first day to the last over all 10 years, but the end dates are exactly 60 days later. To be clear, these 60 day periods are overlapping (one would share 59 days with the next one, 58 with the next, and so on).

Next I pick a threshold rating, say 5, where I want to categorize everything below it into a "bad" category and everything above into a "good" category. I could easily add another field and use a case structure to give every 60-day range a "good" or "bad" flag.

Then to sum it up, I want to display the total periods of "good" and "bad" from maximum beginning to maximum end date. This is where I'm stuck. I could group by the good/bad category and then just take min(start date) and max(end date), but then if, say, the ranges go from good to bad to good then to bad again, output would show overlapping ranges of good and bad. In the aforementioned situation, I would want to show four different ranges.

I realize this may seem clearer to me that it would to someone else so if you need clarification just ask.

Thank you

---EDIT---

Here's an example of what the before would look like:

StartDate| EndDate| MoodRating
------------+------------+------------
1/1/1991  |3/1/1991 | 7
1/2/1991  |3/2/1991 | 7
1/3/1991  |3/3/1991 | 4
1/4/1991  |3/4/1991 | 4
1/5/1991  |3/5/1991 | 7
1/6/1991  |3/6/1991 | 7
1/7/1991  |3/7/1991 | 4
1/8/1991  |3/8/1991 | 4
1/9/1991  |3/9/1991 | 4

And the after:

MinStart| MaxEnd | Good/Bad
-----------+------------+----------
1/1/1991|3/2/1991 |good
1/3/1991|3/4/1991 |bad
1/5/1991|3/6/1991 |good
1/7/1991|3/9/1991 |bad

Currently my query with the group by rating would show:

MinStart| MaxEnd | Good/Bad
-----------+------------+----------
1/1/1991|3/6/1991 |good
1/3/1991|3/9/1991 |bad

This is something along the lines of

select min(StartDate), max(EndDate), Good_Bad
from sourcetable
group by Good_Bad

Comment: This is a good start to a question.  Please add some sample data - and the results you expect.  That will help everyone understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added an edit @stan

Comment: Also, please share the query you're using.

Comment: Hmm - I could do this with a `CURSOR`, but there has to be a better way.  Great question!

Comment: Why would you use a cursor? Unless I'm thinking about the problem wrong, the is easy enough to do with a set based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Jason A Long's answer may be correct - I can't read it or figure it out, so I figured I would post my own answer.  Assuming that this isn't a process that you're going to be constantly running, the `CURSOR`'s performance hit shouldn't matter.  But (at least to me) this solution is very readable and can be easily modified.

In a nutshell - we insert the first record from your source table into our results table.  Next, we grab the next record and see if the mood score is the same as the previous record.  If it is, we simply update the previous record's end date with the current record's end date (extending the range).  If not, we insert a new record.  Rinse, repeat.  Simple.

Here is your setup and some sample data:

```
DECLARE @MoodRanges TABLE (StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE, MoodRating int)

INSERT INTO @MoodRanges
VALUES
('1/1/1991','3/1/1991', 7),
('1/2/1991','3/2/1991', 7),
('1/3/1991','3/3/1991', 4),
('1/4/1991','3/4/1991', 4),
('1/5/1991','3/5/1991', 7),
('1/6/1991','3/6/1991', 7),
('1/7/1991','3/7/1991', 4),
('1/8/1991','3/8/1991', 4),
('1/9/1991','3/9/1991', 4)
```

Next, we can create a table to store our results, as well as some variable placeholders for our cursor:

```
DECLARE @MoodResults TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE, MoodScore varchar(50))
DECLARE @CurrentStartDate DATE, @CurrentEndDate DATE, @CurrentMoodScore INT, 
        @PreviousStartDate DATE, @PreviousEndDate DATE, @PreviousMoodScore INT
```

Now we put all of the sample data into our CURSOR:

```
DECLARE MoodCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT StartDate, EndDate, MoodRating
FROM @MoodRanges

OPEN MoodCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MoodCursor INTO @CurrentStartDate, @CurrentEndDate, @CurrentMoodScore

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    IF @PreviousStartDate IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN

        IF (@PreviousMoodScore >= 5 AND @CurrentMoodScore >= 5)
        OR  (@PreviousMoodScore < 5 AND @CurrentMoodScore < 5)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE @MoodResults
                SET EndDate = @CurrentEndDate
                WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @MoodResults)
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO 
                @MoodResults
                VALUES
                (@CurrentStartDate, @CurrentEndDate, CASE WHEN @CurrentMoodScore >= 5 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END)
            END
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO 
            @MoodResults
            VALUES
            (@CurrentStartDate, @CurrentEndDate, CASE WHEN @CurrentMoodScore >= 5 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END)
        END


    SET @PreviousStartDate = @CurrentStartDate
    SET @PreviousEndDate = @CurrentEndDate
    SET @PreviousMoodScore = @CurrentMoodScore

    FETCH NEXT FROM MoodCursor INTO @CurrentStartDate, @CurrentEndDate, @CurrentMoodScore
    END

CLOSE MoodCursor
DEALLOCATE MoodCursor
```

And here are the results:

```
SELECT * FROM @MoodResults

ID          StartDate  EndDate    MoodScore
----------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
1           1991-01-01 1991-03-02 GOOD
2           1991-01-03 1991-03-04 BAD
3           1991-01-05 1991-03-06 GOOD
4           1991-01-07 1991-03-09 BAD
```

Comment: While Jason Longs also worked, I found this to be a bit more intuitive to me.  Thanks to both of you for your help

Comment: @DougMacArthur Also, you could consolidate the conditional logic into one if/else statement, but I didn't know how familiar you were with this, so I used this format.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyDailyMood', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #MyDailyMood;

CREATE TABLE #MyDailyMood (
    TheDate DATE NOT NULL,
    MoodLevel INT NOT NULL 
    );

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),
    cte_Calendar (dt) AS (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(dd, '2007-01-01', '2017-01-01'))
            DATEADD(dd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2007-01-01')
        FROM
            cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b
        )
INSERT #MyDailyMood (TheDate, MoodLevel)  
SELECT 
    c.dt,
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) + 1
FROM
    cte_Calendar c;

--==========================================================

WITH 
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            RN = ISNULL(NULLIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mdm.TheDate) % 60, 0), 60)
        FROM
            #MyDailyMood mdm
        ),
    cte_AssignGroups AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            DateGroup = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY arn.RN ORDER BY arn.TheDate)
        FROM
            cte_AddRN arn
        )
SELECT 
    BegOfRange = MIN(ag.TheDate),
    EndOfRange = MAX(ag.TheDate),
    AverageMoodLevel = AVG(ag.MoodLevel),
    CASE WHEN AVG(ag.MoodLevel) >= 5 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END 
FROM
    cte_AssignGroups ag
GROUP BY 
    ag.DateGroup;
```

Post OP update solution...

```
WITH 
    cte_AddRN AS (  -- Add a row number to each row that resets to 1 ever 60 rows.
        SELECT 
            *,
            RN = ISNULL(NULLIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mdm.TheDate) % 60, 0), 60)
        FROM
            #MyDailyMood mdm
        ),
    cte_AssignGroups AS (   -- Use DENSE_RANK to create groups based on the RN added above.
                            -- How it works: RN set the row number 1 - 60 then repeats itself
                            -- but we dont want ever 60th row grouped together. We want blocks of 60 consecutive rows grouped together
                            -- DENSE_RANK accompolishes this by ranking within all the "1's", "2's"... and so on.
                            -- verify with the following query... SELECT * FROM cte_AssignGroups ag ORDER BY ag.TheDate
        SELECT 
            *,
            DateGroup = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY arn.RN ORDER BY arn.TheDate)
        FROM
            cte_AddRN arn
        ),
    cte_AggRange AS (   -- This is just a straight forward aggregation/rollup. It produces the results similar to the sample data you posed in your edit.
        SELECT 
            BegOfRange = MIN(ag.TheDate),
            EndOfRange = MAX(ag.TheDate),
            AverageMoodLevel = AVG(ag.MoodLevel),
            GorB = CASE WHEN AVG(ag.MoodLevel) >= 5 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END,
            ag.DateGroup
        FROM
            cte_AssignGroups ag
        GROUP BY 
            ag.DateGroup
        ),
    cte_CompactGroup AS (   -- This time we're using dense rank to group all of the consecutive "Good" and "Bad" values so that they can be further aggregated below.
        SELECT 
            ar.BegOfRange, ar.EndOfRange, ar.AverageMoodLevel, ar.GorB, ar.DateGroup,
            DenseGroup = ar.DateGroup - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ar.GorB ORDER BY ar.BegOfRange)
        FROM
            cte_AggRange ar
        )
-- The final aggregation step...
SELECT 
    BegOfRange = MIN(cg.BegOfRange),
    EndOfRange = MAX(cg.EndOfRange),
    cg.GorB
FROM
    cte_CompactGroup cg
GROUP BY 
    cg.DenseGroup,
    cg.GorB
ORDER BY 
    BegOfRange;
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but I'm still trying to figure out how. It seems to hinge on dense_rank(), what is that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql  It's just a means to create the grouping divisions. Give me a few mins and I'll report the 2nd block of code with som inline comments to help explain what's happening at each CTE level...

Comment: Inline comments have been added. Note: checking the results of each CTE can make it easier to see what each of them are doing. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: What is the purpose of `SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(dd, '2007-01-01', '2017-01-01'))`??  Wouldn't that always evaluate to 3653?  Why not just say `SELECT TOP 3653`?

Comment: You are correct. I coded it that way to make it obvious that I was creating 10 years worth of dates. Yes, I could have hard coded 3653 and use an inline comment... but I didn't...